# How to upload files using PUT instead of POST with PHP

Tags: php, rest, put, http-put

I'm building my first REST Api and it's going well so far, i'm just having an issue with files uploads via `PUT` request method. I need to be `PUT` because i'm updating a user and their avatar image from an iOS app, and PUT is specifically for update requests.

So when I `PUT` and file upload, the `$_FILES` array is actually empty, but when I print the `PUT` data

```
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $put_vars);  
$data = $put_vars; 
print_r($data);
```

I get the following response;

```
Array
(
    [------WebKitFormBoundarykwXBOhO69MmTfs61
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => \"avatar\"; filename=\"avatar-filename.png\"
Content-Type: image/png

�PNG


)
```

Now I don't really understand this `PUT` data because I can't just access it like an array or anything. So my question is how do I access the uploaded file from the `PUT` data?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you sending the PUT request?

Comment: I'm sending it using `Restkit` for iOS but right now i'm actually testing it using `Postman` Google Chrome extension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP provides support for the HTTP PUT method used by some clients to store files on a server. PUT requests are much simpler than a file upload using POST requests and they look something like this:

```
PUT /path/filename.html HTTP/1.1
```

The following code is in the [official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php) for uploading files via PUT:

```
<?php
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
$fp = fopen("myputfile.ext", "w");

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time
   and write to the file */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);

/* Close the streams */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
?>
```

Comment: @Wasim if you are respecting HTTP, there shouldn't be any more data in the PUT request.

Comment: So what if i'm updating my user, not only do I `PUT` the image, I also 'PUT' a new name and biography, will the other string values not be in the same `$data` array as the image?

Comment: Perform one PUT request for each action. Will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Dammit, I was really hoping to consolidate it all to one PHP method for updating a user, looks like I have to split it up. Thanks for your help!

Comment: While still possible (with string manuplulation on the PUT data), it will be much cleaner and good practice to use one request per request.

Comment: It's not actually working with the code above, it writes an empty file. One thing I noticed is that I actually have a key `avatar` for the file, and nowhere can I specific a key. What can I do?

Comment: Your PUT request may be only sending the file path on the client device, rather than the file contents. I'm not sure how iOS works, but check out the documentation for Restkit

Comment: Cheers Greg, i've since decided to stick with the easier option of `POST` with file uploads, a million times simpler.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of this in the PHP Manual: [File Upload: PUT Method](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php).

```
<?php
/* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

/* Open a file for writing */
$fp = fopen("myputfile.ext", "w");

/* Read the data 1 KB at a time
   and write to the file */
while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
  fwrite($fp, $data);

/* Close the streams */
fclose($fp);
fclose($putdata);
?>
```